# Retaining last position of vessel position in geodataframe including time series?

Tags: python, geopandas, time-series, pandas, geodataframe

I have geodataframe about vessel position which include unique code called 'mmsi' and time series. In the following 'mmsi' column has more than 1 'mmsi' code and time series (* mark).

```
           mmsi                 time
98    525107006  2018-12-07T23:55:48
295   563038200  2018-12-07T23:52:42
627   477162400  2018-12-07T23:49:50
704   244850097  2018-12-07T23:47:41
1141  352366000  2018-12-07T23:30:00*
1166  376265000  2018-12-07T23:28:29
1319  352366000  2018-12-07T23:19:53*
1345  477858800  2018-12-07T23:18:14
```

How to retain last position of a vessel of 1 'mmsi' considering the latest time and remove the rest?

I expect that it can be execute in a loop for other 'mmsi' code that have same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by time and [drop duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) mmsis keeping last:

```
newdf = df.sort_values('time').drop_duplicates('mmsi', keep='last')
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much @BERA :-)